# rails counter cache and foreign key test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

This is my favorite designer model

**favorite_designer.rb**

```
class FavoriteDesigner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :designer, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :designer_id

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_presence_of :designer_id

  validates_numericality_of :user_id, :unless => Proc.new{|f| f.user_id.blank?}
  validates_numericality_of :designer_id, :unless => Proc.new{|f| f.designer_id.blank?}
end
```

How can I test `:counter_cache => true and :foreign_key => :designer_id` in rspec with shoulda?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `counter_cache` and `with_foreign_key` shoulda matchers :

```
it { should belong_to(:organization).counter_cache(true) }

it { should have_many(:worries).with_foreign_key('worrier_id') }
```

For full doc and examples look at :

[Counter cache doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/369e9d4c36cf4057eccd997bbb006d838b5aac0f/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L183)

[Foreign key doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/369e9d4c36cf4057eccd997bbb006d838b5aac0f/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L125)